# how to attach an API gateway endpoint to an API gateway created in a different cdk stack

Tags: typescript, aws-api-gateway, aws-cdk, aws-cdk-typescript

I have a main stack (shared resources) and several worker stacks. My main stack contains an api gateway resource, I pass this into the worker stacks that will attach a new endpoint to this resource for their associated functions.

here is a breakdown of the code:

`main-stack.ts` - creates api gateway resource

```
export class MainSlackBotStack extends cdk.Stack {
  public readonly basicAuthorizerFunction: apigateway.RequestAuthorizer;
  public readonly api: apigateway.RestApi;
  constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props: MainSlackBotStackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);
    // create api gateway 
    this.api = new apigateway.RestApi(this, 'MainSlackBotApi', {
      restApiName: 'MainSlackBotApi',
      description: 'This service is the api gateway for the Slack Bot',
      deployOptions: {
        stageName: "v1",
      },
      defaultCorsPreflightOptions: {
        allowHeaders: [
          "Content-Type",
          "X-Amz-Date",
          "Authorization",
          "X-Api-Key",
        ],
        allowMethods: ["OPTIONS", "POST"],
        allowCredentials: true,
        allowOrigins: ["*"],
      },
    });
  }
}
```

`worker-stack.ts` - passed api gateway & creates its own path/ POST request on it

```
// initialize main api
const mainApi = apigateway.RestApi.fromRestApiAttributes(this, `MainApi`, {
    restApiId: props.apiId,
    rootResourceId: props.apiRootResourceId,
});
// add api gateway endpoint for worker bot
const slackBotEndpoint = mainApi.root.addResource(`${props.namespace}`);
slackBotEndpoint.addMethod(
    "POST",
    new apigateway.LambdaIntegration(commandEntryFunction, {}),
    {
        methodResponses: [{
            statusCode: '200',
            responseParameters: {
                'method.response.header.Content-Type': true,
                'method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin': true,
            },
        }],
        authorizer: customAuthorizerFunction,
        authorizationType: apigateway.AuthorizationType.CUSTOM,
    },
);
```

So most things are behaving as expected and the API gateway is created successfully in the main stack, the POST requests are attached to the API gateway *resource* but they are not being attached at the API gateway *stage*.

As a result, I can't make any calls to the worker stack endpoint attachments against the deployed API gateway stage. The stage only displays the API root and associated options request that are defined in the main stack. I think I need to force a new deployment against the API gateway resource but I can't seem to find a solid way of going about that. Anyone encounter this before/ have a clean solution?

Comment: Don't pass the API attributes, pass the entire `RestApi` construct between stacks.

Comment: So this was actually my first approach and definitely feels like the best practice approach but it creates a cyclical reference problem:

`Error: 'MainSlackBotStack' depends on 'HelloWorldWorkerBot' ({MainSlackBotStack/MainSlackBotApi/Deployment/Resource}.addDependency({HelloWorldWorkerBot/helloWorldCustomAuthorizerFunction/Resource}), MainSlackBotStack -> HelloWorldWorkerBot/helloWorldCommandEntryFunction/Resource.Arn). Adding this dependency (HelloWorldWorkerBot -> MainSlackBotStack/MainSlackBotApi/Resource.Ref) would create a cyclic reference.`

Comment: using addDependency also throws the same error

Comment: Yeah addDependency wouldn't work for sure.

Comment: going 1 step back for a second - why would you define an endpoint on a separate stack?

Comment: api resource is shared across many children stacks (ie constructs). these constructs are a repeated pattern of lambda functions/ queues and the associated permissions that I would like to maintain tighter control of/ reduce the amount of overall code required to deploy them.